# How to select an item from combobox by key?

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, key

I fill the comboBox getting data from the DataBase

This is my DataBase structure:

```
Table names

ID ------ Name

1  ------ John
2  ------ Sarah
3  ------ Peter
```

This is my Class structure

```
// Class structure

    public class Names
    {
        public int id;
        public string name;
    }
```

This is how I declare my dictionary and how I set it

```
// Declare dictionary
Dictionary<int, string> dataSouceNames;

public MyProgram()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    dataSouceNames = getComboDataSourceNames();
}
```

```
//Dictionary
private Dictionary<int, string> getComboDataSourceNames()
{
    Dictionary<int,string> comboSource = new Dictionary<int,string>();

    List<Names> res = dataProvider.getAllNames();

    foreach (Names item in res)
    {
        comboSource.Add(item.id, item.nome);
    }

    return comboSource;
}
```

This is the SQL I've used for getting the data from the DataBase

```
getAllNames()
{
    string sql = "SELECT * FROM names";
}
```

At the end how I fill my ComboBox

```
// Function fill combobox
private void initComboNames()
{
    cmbNames.DataSource = new BindingSource(dataSourceNames, null);
    cmbNames.DisplayMember = "Text";
    cmbNames.ValueMember = "Value";
}
```

Then I try to select item in combobox by key:

```
    cmbNames.SelectedItem = Names.ID // WHERE Names.ID is number "2"
```

I was expect the output "Sarah" as SelectedIndex but I know Im doing It wrong.

Comment: what is the DataSource? `dataSourceNames` or `dataSouceCantieri`? If it's `dataSouceCantieri`, then `cmbNames.SelectedItem = new KeyValuePair<int, string>(Names.ID, dataSouceCantieri[Names.ID]);`. You should have `.DisplayMember = "Value"` (corresposnding to the string, the `Name`) and `.ValueMember = "Key"`. `dataSourceNames` is undeclared and undetermined.

Comment: Hello @Jimi your solution had worked meanwhile I didn't understand what have you done! I read that this is not a chat, but It would be super cool if you explain my what have you wrote. Thank you btw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why I suggested to use this kind of assignment to set the ComboBox's current item:

```
cmbNames.SelectedItem = new KeyValuePair<int, string>(Names.ID, dataSouceCantieri[Names.ID]);
```

and also to define the **`DisplayMember`** and **`ValueMember`** properties like this:

```
cmbNames.DisplayMember = "Value";
cmbNames.ValueMember = "Key";
cmbNames.DataSource = new BindingSource(dataSouceCantieri, null);
```

It's related to what happens when you set **`[ComboBox].DataSource = [Dictionary<TKey, TValue>];`**.
Well, you cannot do that, actually. A Dictionary is a complex object which is not directly managed by the control's `DataSource` property; it only accepts a complex object that implements [IList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ilist) or [IListSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.ilistsource). A Dictionary doesn't.

You can of course convert the Dictionary to a List, it will be now accepted:

```
[ComboBox].DataSource = [Dictionary<TKey, TValue>].ToList();
```

We're providing a **`List<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>`**, which implements **`IList<T>`**.
Also, each element of the List is a [`KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.keyvaluepair-2).
This object exposes two properties: **`Key`** and **`Value`**, which allows to access the object's inner values.
A Dictionary only exposes the [Keys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.keys) collection and the [Values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.values) collection properties. Other *complex* objects.

When you set a **`BindingSource.DataSource`** to a Dictionary, this class performs the same operation: it tests whether the object we're assigning implements `IList` or `IListSource`; if it doesn't, it creates a new [BindingList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.bindinglist-1) and uses the [IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.ienumerable.getenumerator) method to extract the elements from the collection.
[Dictionary.GetEnumerator()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.getenumerator) returns each element of the collection as a **`KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>`**, the same as calling `[Dictionary].ToList()`.

See this behaviour in the .Net Reference Source:

[BindingSource main constructor](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/BindingSource.cs,114)
[IList list = [BindingSource].GetListFromEnumerable()](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/BindingSource.cs,839)
[private static IList CreateBindingList(Type type)](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/BindingSource.cs,687)

So, when we assign this:

```
cmbNames.DataSource = new BindingSource(dataSourceNames, null);
```

we actually set the Control's DataSource to a **`IList<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>`**.
As a consenquence, each `ComboBox.Item` is a `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>`.
A `KeyValuePair<int, string>`, here.
That's why we can set:

```
[ComboBox].DisplayMember = "Value";
[ComboBox].ValueMember = "Key";
```

those are the names of the properties exposed by the `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>` class.

Since each Item of the ComboBox is a `KeyValuePair<int, string>`, to select an item, making it the current item, we can set it to a specific `KeyValuePair<int, string>`.
In your case, the Key is provided by the **`Names.ID`** property:

```
cmbNames.SelectedItem = new KeyValuePair<int, string>(Names.ID, dataSouceCantieri[Names.ID]);
```

I used this form: **`new KeyValuePair<int, string>(Names.ID, dataSouceCantieri[Names.ID])`** because this way we can access the Dictionary, **`dataSouceCantieri`**, directly by Key, so this is a `O(1)` operation.

Better than writing:

```
cmbNames.SelectedItem = dataSouceCantieri.FirstOrDefault(dict => dict.Key == Names.ID);
```

or similar. This method implies iterating the collection until the right element is found or none is.

Comment: Your are the man! This explanation was the best you could do, neither in the microsoft docs I could find a similar explanation! I would like to donate

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to pass name ("Sarah" instead of Id "2"), if not possible use SelectedValue.

```
cmbNames.SelectedValue = Names.Id;
```

Otherwise if you know the index, this can be done

```
cmbNames.SelectedIndex= 1;
```

Comment: Unfortunately I dont have the Index and neither I can pass the name "Sarah" because in my DataBase I save values as numbers...

Comment: Can you try this and see -> cmbNames.SelectedValue = Names.Id; Updated answer as well above.

Answer (score 0):

First you fill combobox in this way . by this the comboBox will show name (Display member) to the user but when you select an index it will give you ID (value member)

```
SQL.con.Open();
DataTable tb = new DataTable();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select columnID,Name from TableName",SQL.con);
SqlDataReader dr;
dr = cmb.ExecuteReader();
tb.Load(dr);
comboBox.DisplayMember = "Name";
comboBox.ValueMember = "columnID";
comboBox.DataSource = tb;
```

When you are finish whith this you can simply get id by

```
int id =  comboBox.SelectedValue;
```

Remember the change of the fields like comboboc , columnId etc with your desire field